# Render CAEmitterLayer (somehow)

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, caemitterlayer, caemittercell

I really need to capture a CAEmitterLayer as an image to render in my context. I know that renderInContext method does not suport CAEmitterLayer, i have found many questions about it but no good answers.

I was able to achieve my goal by using new iOS7 method drawViewHierarchyInRect, it worked just fine, but i need my app running on iOS6 as well.

There is any way at all to do that? Can i, programmatically, take a screenshot like when i press homebutton + powerbutton on device?

Any help will be useful, i'm on a dead alley with this.

Comment: Drop support for 6. Lots of people tried to get it to work but never did. Or try using the private method but obfuscated (unlikely to succeed but YMMV.)

Comment: Did You got solution for this. i am face also same issue

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, the CAEmitterLayer can not be "renderincontext", but i read a blog, at last the author said there is a way to draw it,and output a image to show,here is the blog for you.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/6063/uikit-particle-systems-in-ios-5-tutorial

Comment: Please post a more complete answer, if the link ever goes down this answer won't be very useful.

Comment: I've seen this post, but he didn't show how to, he just told that is possible. In the end i kind of created my own particle emitter system, it was not perfect but worked well for my app.

Comment: i find a method can capture the screen, it used like this               "       CGImageRef UIGetScreenImage();   
        CGImageRef img = UIGetScreenImage();